# Unable to load MS edge chromium with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, nunit, selenium-webdriver-c#, edge-chromium

I'm trying to load the msedge chromium. encountering error.

Steps to recreate:

1. Installed mschromium Beta and Dev versions.
2. Installed the Nuget package "Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver -Version 4.0.0-alpha04"
3. placed the msedgedriver.exe in location which I mentioned in the code.
4. still code throwing  error.

   ```
   public void Test1()
   {


       // EdgeOptions() requires using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge
       // Construct EdgeOptions with is_legacy = false
       var edgeOptions = new OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeOptions(false);
       edgeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\msedge.exe";

       var msedgedriverDir = @"E:\XXXXX\#######\YYYYYY\ZZZZZZ\MSEdgeChromium\bin\Debug";
       var msedgedriverExe = @"msedgedriver.exe";

       // Construct EdgeDriverService with is_legacy = false too
       var service = OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(msedgedriverDir, msedgedriverExe, false);
       service.EnableVerboseLogging = true;

       var driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver(service, edgeOptions);
       Assert.Pass();
   }
   ```

> ErrorDetails: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added the `msedgedriver.exe` to your project manually you also need to set the `Copy to Output Directory` property of the file.

Because non-code files are default not placed in the build directory `bin\Debug`. Double check the driver is indeed copied to the directory.

Instead of hardcoding the path to the output directory you could try:

```
var msedgedriverDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

See: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53248.visual-studio-copying-files-to-debug-or-release-folder.aspx

Comment: Its working Bro. Thank you so much